# Steam account changed

Tags: dota-2

I have Dota 2 on my PC on a steam account. If I create another account will I loose my games or will they be in the second account also?
Any solutions if I want them in another account?

Comment: Sorry for the picture I had to enlarge my question

Comment: There is no need at all to enlarge your question. Short questions are just as valid as long ones. Also, adding irrelevant content to a question is not the right way to enlarge your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a second account for Steam to play Dota on it then you will not lose your games or anything linked to your current Steam account. However you will have to 1. Sign out of your current account and sign into the new one to actually play Dota 2 on it and 2. Repeat this step everytime you want to play Dota on each account.

With Steam however there is a mechanic in the client that should you create a new account and sign into it on your main PC the client will recognise that there are steam apps installed on the machine and ask you if you would like to share some of them. This means you dont have to re-download what would be copy of Dota to your hard-drive.

I've create multiple accounts for Steam for the purpose of [smurfing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/where-does-the-term-smurfing-come-from) on them in different games so this is a regular occurrence for people to create second or even third accounts to play fresh especially if there is a ranking system in a game like Dota and CS:GO.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 steam accounts, but the games on each account are separate. if you have paid for a game on one account, you don't automatically get that on another account you make. Similarly, any progression you make in a game, including savegames, profiles, achievements, microtransactions and ingame purchases, are locked to the account that the purchases are made with. Just about the only thing that is shared between accounts is game installs on the same machine: if you have 2 steam accounts with the same game licensed on both accounts, you do not need to download that game separately for each account.

Dota 2 is a free game, so you don't need to pay to get a second account with the game active. However, anything you have unlocked on your main account, like playable characters, cosmetic unlocks and ranking, is linked to your main account, so if you have put in a lot of effort into your main account, the things you put effort into on your main account won't be available on the second account.

Note that in the Dota 2 community, the use of a second account is frequent among top player and even has a name: Smurfing. This is usually done to try out new tactics without breaking the ranking of the main account.

Comment: Extra info: Firstly, it is possible to move some things, like savegames, across accounts by moving certain files (i.e. savegame files). Secondly, just to clarify for that last sentence, you won't lose it, it just won't be avaliable on the second account.